# Suppose that f(x), g(x), and h(x) are polynomials with integer coefficients such that f(x)=g(x)h(x).

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $f(x), g(x)$, and $h(x)$ are polynomials with integer coefficients such that $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$.
Suppose that $p$ is a prime number and $r$ is an integer such that $f(r)\equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Then prove that $g(r) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ or  $h(r)\equiv 0\pmod p$.

I am not sure , If can I use the identity that if $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$ for this question?
Could you please help me with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(r)=g(r)h(r)$ is just writing the integer $f(r)$ as the product of two integers $g(r)$ and $h(r)$. So the polynomials don't really matter, and you can use the result that you stated.